# Algorithm for necessary / sufficient conditions

Tags: algorithm, logic

I have a set of conditions each of which can be one of Optional, Necessary or Sufficient. Clearly the set is met if any of the sufficients are true. And if all of the necessaries are true. (Optionals are irrelevant).

But obviously this simplifies because if I find any sufficient condition is true, I don't need to keep on looking (it's met). And if any of the necessaries are false, then the set can't be met. So  in pseudo-code

```
for(condition c in conditions) {
    if condition.Necessary:
        if !condition.evaluate() return false
    else if condition.Sufficient
        if condition.evaluate() return true
}

return ???
```

So I'm stuck at the last bit. What's the test at the end? I had simply "must be true" but that breaks with a set of size 1 with a sufficient condition that's not met. Is there a short-cut, or do I need to just evaluate all the conditions and count the cases?

Comment: Please explain in plain English, what do you want to happen if no Sufficient is satisfied, and all Necessary are? _I don't know_ is a valid answer, if ternary logic return value is acceptable.

Comment: The return should be true if any sufficient or all necessary conditions are met.False otherwise. "Don't know" is not an option :-)

Comment: _If_ there is a guarantee that either any sufficient or all necessary are met, the code shall not reach the `return ???` line. Throw an exception there, if your language supports them, or set some fatal error indication otherwise.

Comment: I think you're saying that if there's no necessary conditions, then the result should be false even though all necessary conditions are satisfied. I don't think you have a programming problem -- you have a requirements (or possibly logic) problem.

Comment: @PaulHankin I don't think so! I'm writing a game where each mission has a set of objectives to determine if the player has succeeded. Every tick, the objectives are evaluated to see if they have been met. They have the necessary / sufficient / optional criteria. There was a bug that a single sufficient condition that failed would default to true (returning false at the end in the above loop fails other tests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But obviously this simplifies because if I find any sufficient condition is true, I don't need to keep on looking (it's met). And if any of the necessaries are false, then the set can't be met.

Not necessarily, unless there's an unstated assumption that the set of conditions does not contain a contradiction (e.g. there's a necessary/false and a sufficient/true).  Unless you can prove that there's no contradiction, the simplification doesn't actually hold.

If the interpretation is

- true: any sufficient is true or all necessaries are true
- false: all sufficients are false or any necessary is false

then (subject to the above note about contradictions)

```
boolean allNecessariesTrue = false

for (condition c in conditions) {
  if condition.Necessary:
    if !condition.evaluate():
      return false
    else
      allNecessariesTrue = true
  if condition.Sufficient:
    if condition.evaluate() return true

return allNecessariesTrue
```